# Content control for complex layout

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I start to learn winrt so I have question regarding containers in xaml.
I want to have on main screen of my app a set of different custom controls, but i want to have such interface like in Gridview (Horizontal scrolling, names for groups).
Yes, I can use GridView with different templates per item. But it's not a good solution.

For better explanation please review my picture. It's my goal.[image: this I want to have]

How can I do this? Should i write some kind of custom GridView or there is already such or similar controls?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the following:-

-Scroll Viewer
  - StackPanel (orientation horizontal)
     -Grid view
     -User Control
     -...

If you are targeting 8.1 then you can use the new hubs which are designed exactly for the described scenario.

Comment: Thank you. In next couple days will try this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately it raise an error. Not enough memory it says. Not sure why this happens.